# Norton <-> Thévenin equivalents with complex impedances

Tags: thevenin, norton

Given a Thévenin equivalent circuit, it's pretty easy to convert to the Norton equivalent, or vice versa:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9nw87.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Although the value of the voltage or current source changes, the resistance *R* is the same either way.

But what if this is an AC circuit, and *R* is not a resistance, but a complex impedance? Is some additional calculation required or does the impedance remain unchanged?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX8SVd.png)</sup>

In other words, what's the relationship between *Z<sub>t</sub>* and *Z<sub>n</sub>*, and *V* and *I*?

Answer (score 2):

If you imagine a load attached to the circuit, to get the equivalent the current and voltage sourced to the load needs to be the same if you change the circuit.

If we go from the Thevenin to the Norton equivalent we get this current at the load:

\$ V_t = Z_t*I_n \$

and equivalently to go back

\$ \frac{V_t}{Z_t} = I_n \$

The transform for the impedance is:

\$ Z_t= \frac{1}{Y_n} \$

These still work for phasors because complex operations are equivalent and because [Ohms law](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145179/how-does-ohms-law-extend-to-z-if-z-is-complex/145180) and [Kirchoffs laws](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/250784/kirchhoffs-laws-in-phasor-domain) can be extended to phasors/complex operations.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvPimb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

An impedance is still measured in Ohms. you can still notate capacitors and inductors as impedances in ohms using phasor notation, then the same rules for reduction apply as in the average basic electrical engineering course.

So the R value seen above then becomes a phasor. Using this method, voltage/current should also be converted to a phasor, but this is academic as you can mostly read from the specification/question formulation. Just be aware that the magnitude of this voltage/current phasor will be the RMS, not the peak voltage.

Comment: So you're saying I can use the same equations as long as I do them all with phasors? I'm a little reluctant to believe it, since every reference I find uses _R_ and "resistance" in the equations and explanation.

Comment: in essence, yes. only it isn't a resistance R anymore, it's an impedance Z, which encompasses both resistive and reactive components. the same rules apply to impedances as they do to resistances.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing in the analytic derivation of Norton and Thevenin equivalents that precludes: \$\small V_{TH} \$; \$\small I_N \$; \$\small R_{TH} \$; \$\small R_N \$; and \$\small R_L \$ from being complex numbers.